# How to use promises with different cases to resolve

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I was using promises in my code dealing with async problems. But, I have to resolve an entire web scraping procedure before implementing the next step. I tried doing something like putting it all in the `resolve` section. Can someone guide me?

```
function ScrapeAsync() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
        resolve(
            //Scrape
            //company = (response.match(/<span class="product-sub-title">/)[1]);
            console.log(company);
        )
    })
}

ScrapeAsync().then(function(){
    console.log(dbFoodItems)
    console.log(dbFoodItems[item])
    console.log(dbFoodItems[item].company)
});
```

Fuller code:

```
//Function evoked when screen switched
var buttonClicked = function() {

    console.log("Redirection");

    //Constructor for food items
    var Food = function(code) {
        this.code = code;

    };
    //Iterate over all items stored in barcodeList
    console.log(barcodeList)
    console.log(dbFoodItems)



    barcodeList.forEach(function(item) {

        //Evaluates true food item not already in database
        if (!(item in dbFoodItems)) {

            //Create new object with food constructor
            dbFoodItems[item] = new Food(item);

            console.log(dbFoodItems);
            console.log(item);


            //Variables used in the URL

            var upc = item
            var epoch = (new Date).getTime();
            var base = "https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca"

            var firstURL = "https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/search/"+ epoch + "/page/~item/" + upc + "/~sort/recommended/~selected/true"


            //Varibles to store retrieved data

            var company;
            //var name;
            //var quantity;
            //var price;
            //var ingredients;
            //var image;


            //Scrape the first URL
            $.get(firstURL, function(response){

                //Retrieve link to item URL

                var link = response.match(/<a href="(.*?)" class="product-name"/)[1];
                console.log(link)


                //Scrape item URL

                $.get(base + link, function(response){
                    /*function ScrapeAsync() {
                        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                            resolve(
                                //Scrape the required data using regex
                                //company = (response.match(/<span class="product-sub-title">\n\s\s\s\s\s\s(.*?)&nbsp; <\/span>/)[1]);
                                dbFoodItems[item].company = company)
                                console.log(company);
                                console.log(dbFoodItems[item].company)

                        })
                    }*/

                    function ScrapeAsync() {
                        return new Promise(function(resolve){
                            resolve(response.match(/<span class="product-sub-title">\n\s\s\s\s\s\s(.*?)&nbsp; <\/span>/)[1])
                        })
                    }


                    //name = (response.match(/(.*?)<span class="product-name-qty"> (.*?)<\/span>/)[1]).trim();
                    //quantiy = response.match(/(.*?)<span class="product-name-qty"> \((.*?)\)<\/span>/)[2];
                    //price = response.match(/<span class="reg-price-text">(.*?)<\/span>/)[1];
                    //ingredients = response.match(/Ingredients\n\s\s\s\s\s<\/div>\n\s\s\s\s\s(.*?)\n\s\s\s\s<\/div>/)[1];
                    //image = response.match(/<img srcset="(.*?)"/)[1];

                    //console.log(name);
                    //console.log(quantiy);
                    //console.log(price);
                    //console.log(ingredients);
                    //console.log(image);
                })
            });
              ScrapeAsync().then(function(company){
                        dbFoodItems[item].company = company
                        console.log(dbFoodItems[item])
                    });

            //if (company != undefined) {

            //}
        }
    })

    console.log(dbFoodItems)
    foodItemsRef.set(dbFoodItems);
}
```

Comment: You have to *call* resolve after the asynchronous code is done. But you don't have any asynchronous code up top, so why use a Promise? (if that's not your actual code, post the full code?)

Comment: Promises  resolve function is just like ordinary javascript function, you can't put a block of statements as an argument to resolve and expect it to work

Comment: @CertainPerformance I was trying to simplify the question, though I included the entire code.

Comment: `ScrapeAsync` still isn't doing anything asynchronous though, right? It's just doing a simple regular expression match, so there's no point in making it a Promise

Comment: It is doing asynchronous stuff. The `.then` part is outside the loop and the promise is inside the loop. The `.then` part was happening before the promise (before I added the promise) @CertainPerformance

Comment: why is `function ScrapeAsync()` returning a promise? all the code it is doing is **synchronous** - you are overcomplicating something very simple - though, the problem is that `ScrapeAsync` is defined **inside** `$.get(base + link, function(response) {` but you're trying to call it from **outside** that callback - so, you **should** be getting an error in your console that `ScrapeAsync` does not exist! A fact you failed to mention!

Answer (score 0):

One of your main problems is where `function ScrapeAsync` is declared it is not callable where you call it

However, the code in general is not making use of Promises at all - one thing that will help is knowing that `$.get` returns a Promise-like object that is Promise-like enough to be handled with Promise.all

This uses Promise.all to wait for all the Promises (and some undefined's, it doesn't matter) before calling `foodItemsRef.set(dbFoodItems);`

inside the `.map` loop, a promise is returned which isn't resolved until that whole promise chain completes

The added benefit is, no callback nesting pyramid of doom

```
var buttonClicked = function() {
    console.log("Redirection");
    var Food = function(code) {
        this.code = code;
    };
    console.log(barcodeList)
    console.log(dbFoodItems)
    Promise.all(barcodeList.map(function(item) {
        if (!(item in dbFoodItems)) {
            dbFoodItems[item] = new Food(item);
            console.log(dbFoodItems);
            console.log(item);
            var upc = item
            var epoch = (new Date).getTime();
            var base = "https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca"
            var firstURL = "https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca/search/" + epoch + "/page/~item/" + upc + "/~sort/recommended/~selected/true"
            return $.get(firstURL)
            .then(function(response) {
                var link = response.match(/<a href="(.*?)" class="product-name"/)[1];
                console.log(link)
                return $.get(base + link);
            }).then(function(response) {
                const company = response.match(/<span class="product-sub-title">\n\s\s\s\s\s\s(.*?)&nbsp; <\/span>/)[1];
                dbFoodItems[item].company = company
                console.log(dbFoodItems[item])
            });
        }
    })).then(function() {
        console.log(dbFoodItems)
        foodItemsRef.set(dbFoodItems);
    });
}
```

edit: I feel it would be remiss of me not to show the more-ES6 version of the above code

```
const buttonClicked = function() {
    const Food = function(code) {
        this.code = code;
    };
    Promise.all(barcodeList.map(function(item) {
        if (!(item in dbFoodItems)) {
            dbFoodItems[item] = new Food(item);
            const epoch = (new Date).getTime();
            const base = "https://www.realcanadiansuperstore.ca";
            const firstURL = `${base}/search/${epoch}/page/~item/${item}/~sort/recommended/~selected/true`;
            return $.get(firstURL)
            .then(response => $.get(`${base}${response.match(/<a href="(.*?)" class="product-name"/)[1]}`)
            .then(response => dbFoodItems[item].company = response.match(/<span class="product-sub-title">\n\s\s\s\s\s\s(.*?)&nbsp; <\/span>/)[1]);
        }
    }))
    .then(() => foodItemsRef.set(dbFoodItems));
}
```